# Changing type of property in index type's mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I have index mapping for type 'T1' as below:

```
"T1" : {
    "properties" : {
        "prop1" : {
            "type" : "text"
        }
    }
}
```

And now I want to change the type of prop1 from `text` to `keyword`. I don't want to delete index. I have also read people suggesting to create another property with new type and replace it. But then I have to update old documents which I am not interested into. I tried to use PUT api as below but I never works.

```
PUT /indexName/T1/_mapping -d
{
    "T1" : {
        "properties" : {
            "prop1" : {
                "type" : "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapping cannot be modified, hence the PUT api you have used will not work. The new index will have to be created with the updated mapping to be used and reindexing all the data to new index. 
To prevent downtime you can always use alias: 
https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime

Answer (score 1):

A mapping cannot be updated once it is persisted. The only option is to create a new index with the correct mappings and reindex your data using the reindex API provided by ES.

You can read about the reindex API here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/docs-reindex.html